# How to download GrapesJS on Mac

Tags: github, download, installation, grapesjs

So there is this open source drag and drop website builder called GrapesJS, I really liked its concept and I want to download and install it, the problem is, I am not knowing how.

Can anyone help me, please? I left a pic for you that indicates what the official sites say in the official download area.

Thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUL81.png)

Comment: Do you see a green button on the right side saying "Clone or Download"? Click that and there you will find "Download ZIP" button.

Comment: where is that button supposed to be again? If you mean on the GrapesJS site then no. If somewhere else then please specify and if it is possible take a screenshot of it, big thank you in advance.

Comment: On their Github page, under the "Code" tab.

Comment: Or wait... install Nodejs from https://nodejs.org and follow the instructions given [here](https://github.com/artf/grapesjs/blob/dev/README.md#development)

Comment: You may also need to install git